# Simple Site Search With PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm looking for a script for a simple search engine that involves only 2 or three variables.

For my site I have a database table named search and 3 fields: url, title, and content.

Can someone please help me build a simple processing script for this please? I would only like the title and the content to be searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a query like:

```
$prepared = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM search WHERE title LIKE "%:search_value%" OR content LIKE "%:search_value%"');
$prepared->execute(array(':search_value' => $search_value));
$rows = $prepared->fetchAll();
```

Where $db is a [PDO object](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: bad practice -- vulnerable to SQL injections. Always use a sql library that can prepare your queries. If you use adodb you get cross-db compatibility for free.

Comment: @j13r - Would a simple mysql_real_escape_string() work or another built in PHP funciton?

Comment: @j13r Alright, I was assuming the $search_value would be sanitized. I'll add it in to be explicitly clear.

Comment: Consider looking into PDO for SQL tasks like this.  Using placeholders can help prevent SQL injections.  It's also useful for many other database related tasks.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that; there are various forms of SQL injections. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690795/am-i-safe-using-just-mysql-real-escape-string-to-defend-sql-injections#5690804 
There is also an example of how to use prepared statements with MySQLi here: http://www.ultramegatech.com/2009/07/using-mysql-prepared-statements-in-php/

Comment: Updated the answer to use prepared statements.

Comment: Hey everyone... This might be pushing it a bit but in my while loop when I display my results I was wondering if their was a way to just grab the 100 characters around the search_value. Again if it's too much then don't bother.